# SQL Server - How would I insert a RANK function to rows that are already sorted in ranked order?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, window-functions, rank

So, apparently, I have everything right according to my professor except for one column that shows the rank of the columns shown in the code below. I'm thinking that, essentially, it just has to show the row numbers off to the left side in its own column. Here are the instructions:

> The sales manager would now like you to create a report that ranks her
>   products by both their total sales and total sales quantity (each will
>   be its own column).   Create a stored procedure that returns the
>   following columns but also with the two new rank columns added.
>
> Product Name |  Orders Count | Total Sales Value | Total Sales
>   Quantity

I know that it doesn't have that extra column in the assignment description, but I guess I need it. Here is what I have so far:

```
USE OnlineStore
GO

CREATE PROC spManagerProductSalesCount
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    P.Name AS 'Product Name',
    Isnull(Count(DISTINCT O.OrderID), 0) AS 'Orders Count',
    Sum(Isnull(O.OrderTotal, 0)) AS 'Total Sales Value',
    Sum (Isnull(OI.OrderItemQuantity, 0)) AS 'Total Sales Quantity'
FROM 
    Product P
INNER JOIN 
    OrderItem OI ON P.ProductID = OI.ProductID
INNER JOIN 
    Orders O on O.OrderID = OI.OrderID
GROUP BY
    P.Name
ORDER BY
    'Total Sales Value' DESC, 'Total Sales Quantity' DESC
END
```

Update: It does need to be in a stored procedure and CTEs can/should be used. I could use some help with the CTEs. Those are pretty difficult for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the select part of the stored proc but it should show you what to do:

```
declare @products table
(
Name varchar(50),
id int
)
declare @orderitems table
(
id int,
orderid int,
productid int,
orderitemquantity int
)
declare @orders table
(
orderid int,
ordertotal decimal(18,2)
)

insert into @products VALUES ('apple', 1)
insert into @products VALUES ('orange', 2)
insert into @products VALUES ('pear', 3)
insert into @products VALUES ('melon', 4)

insert into @orders values(1, 19.0)
insert into @orders values(2, 25.5)
insert into @orders values(3, 9.5)
insert into @orders values(4, 13.5)
insert into @orders values(5, 8.5)

insert into @orderitems VALUES(1, 1, 1, 20)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(2, 1, 2, 10)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(3, 2, 3, 5)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(4, 2, 4, 4)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(5, 3, 1, 10)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(6, 3, 2, 5)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(7, 4, 3, 3)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(8, 4, 4, 2)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(9, 5, 1, 5)
insert into @orderitems VALUES(10, 5, 4, 2)

;WITH summary as 
(
    SELECT p.Name as ProductName, 
    COUNT(o.orderid) as 'Orders Count',
    ISNULL(Sum(o.ordertotal),0) AS 'Total Sales Value',
    ISNULL(Sum(oi.orderitemquantity),0) AS 'Total Sales Quantity'
    FROM @products p
    INNER JOIN @orderitems oi on oi.productid = p.id
    INNER JOIN @orders o on o.orderid = oi.orderid 
    GROUP BY p.Name
)

SELECT ProductName, [Orders Count], [Total Sales Value], [Total Sales Quantity], 
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Total Sales Value] DESC) AS ValueRanking,
RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [Total Sales Quantity] DESC) AS QuantityRanking FROM summary
```

Notice a few things here.  This code can be cut and pasted into a Management Studio query window and run as such.  It starts with some table declarations and insert of sample data.  When asking a question it is always useful if you do this part of the work; people are much more likely to answer, if the most boring bit is done!

COUNT() does not need ISNULL protection; it returns 0, if there are no values.

Given the final data, you will see that the ValueRanking and QuantityRankings are different (I fiddled the data to get this, just to illustrate the point).  What this means is that the final result can only be ordered by one of them (or indeed by any other column - order by is not dependent on ranking).

HTH